# Find a lipschitz constant for the function $f(x) = (\delta + x^2)^{\frac 14}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As in the title, find a lipschitz constant for the function $f(x) = (\delta + x^2)^{\frac 14}$ for $ \delta \in (0,1)$ and $|x| \le 1$

I've taken the derivative and got

$f_x = \frac x{2(\delta + x^2)^{\frac 34}}$.

I'm trying to find an upper bound for $f_x$ to get a lipschitz constant, but if we let $\delta \to 0$ then $f_x \to \infty$ for small $x$, so I was thinking that $1$ would be the lipschitz constant $L$ by plugging in values, but I'm not positive, and I don't know how I would concretely argue this, even if the answer is correct.

Comment: Since you want to find an upper bound for $f_x$, why don't you have look at $f_{xx}$?

Comment: You have a problem with the fixed point: for the most of values of $\delta$ in (0,1) this fixed point it exists but for $x\gt 1$. If $f$ is lipschitzienne in the complet metric space $|x|\le 1$......what must happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
|f_x|= \frac {|x|}{2(\delta + x^2)^{\frac 34}}\le \frac{1}{2\delta^{3/4}}.
$$

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.